# Treat String as Template in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can one utilize a string contained within a variable as a template?

For example:

**Controller**

```
$scope.items = [
    {
         name: "Bruce Wayne"
    },
    {
         name: "Lucius Fox"
    }
];
$scope.template = "<input ng-model='item.name' type='text'>";
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-bind-html="<!-- The `template` variable defined in the controller. -->">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried `$sce.trustAsHtml`, which only doesn't connect with the actual scope when using things like `ng-model='item.name'`. Reading through the `$sce` docs I don't think that it provides anything that can trust a string as a template.

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2n3m0qw/5/) for you to play with.

Comment: have you tried using a `$rootScope` instead? or declaring your template in  a `setTimeout(function(){}, 0)`  ?

Comment: @Nicolas In my case the template is loaded dynamically from a database, so it's already wrapped in an asynchronous callback and no, this doesn't change anything. Assigning to `$rootScope` would still have the item accessible in the `$scope`, just defined in a parent instead. I don't believe that would change anything.

Comment: You should use a directive for things like that. Directives can have it's own scope and controller (among other things), so they are perfect for this. For he html binding itself you can use $sce.trustAsHtml, like you said

Comment: If the template is loaded dinamically from the database, you can use templateProvider for the directive's template.

Comment: @FranePoljak It is loaded from a database, but it's stored in a JSON encoded array, so I don't think I can fetch it by itself from the database, nor do I want to. I really need to take a string and parse it into a template. As to the directive, I've thought and tested a bit of that as well. Take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b2n3m0qw/6/) and tell me if it's what you were thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to actually bind data from ng repeat to input need to compile the html. for that this directive can be used

```
app.directive('dynamic', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                element[0].innerHTML = html;
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div dynamic="template">
   </div>
</div>

$scope.items = [
    {
         name: "Bruce Wayne"
    },
    {
         name: "Lucius Fox"
    }
];
$scope.template = "<input ng-bind='item.name' type='text'>";
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qBtPkWCEDEdwnanARLhG?p=preview)

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b2n3m0qw/4/)? I've already tried that.

Comment: isnt it bad form to change the type of template like that?

Comment: @sachilaranawaka So, this works as is, but, unfortunately, causes major problems when using the `template` variable within the array. See [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/rpinSCyQhovP7PxqLYf0?p=preview). If you look at console you'll see the infinite digest.

Comment: @brhardwick well it depend on the situation also. it take additional resource and time to compile html manually. But if you need data to bind to html from some service this is the way

Comment: @sachilaranawaka Nevermind. This is correct. It's the `$sce.trustAsHtml` that's throwing all the errors. You don't need any `trustAsHtml` when `$complile`ing. Recommend updating answer to remove that, but check [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/rpinSCyQhovP7PxqLYf0?p=preview) and it works.